# Vertical ListView with dynamic width in a Row

Tags: flutter, listview, row

Trying to build a simple layout with 2 pieces in a `Row`: the main part with content and a kind of persistent menu on the left. The left part should be a `ListView`, the content part doesn't matter, for example, Text. The tricky part is to make `ListView`'s width always fit its content, regardless of screen size.

Here's my code with `ConstrainedBox` workaround (pls remove it to get 'pure' issue):

```
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    Text('item $index'),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: const Text(
                  'Some text here',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

So, `ConstrainedBox` is not an ultimate solution, because it's not auto-adjusting to `ListView`'s content.

Of course, there's an option with a scrollable `Column`, which is inappropriate if we have many items to build.

We can wrap `ListView` with a `Flexible` and set a second child, for example, `Expanded(flex: 5, ...` but this option, again, depends on the screen's width, not on the `ListView`'s one.

Wrapping ListView with IntrinsicWidth leads to `RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.` or `RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.` error depending on `shrinkWrap` parameter.

I tried to analyze this layout considering [Constraints go down, sizes go up](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints) principle, and I can't get how to send proper (dynamic!) constraint down to `ListView`, or how to set its width to a minimum. Maybe `ListView` just needs a special parameter for this, like 'crossAxisFit' or something.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no solution to your problem.

> make `ListView`'s width always fit its content

> there's an option with a scrollable `Column`, which is inappropriate if we have many items to build

Here is the tricky part: if we have a lot of items to build, the `ListView` doesn't know about the width of its children before they appear in your view (approximately). It also might forget about the previous children as you scroll down (depends on parameters). So unless you want your `ListView` to constantly change its width as you scroll through it, your problem is unsolvable. Best way to achieve something close is being able to calculate the maximum width of your `ListView` children and then use it as a `maxWidth` constraint in your example code.

If you are actually making a menu, there should not be too many items, so I would just use a `Column`.